# missing Axhost after using axImp.exe

Tags: axhost

I hope someone could help me out.

My original task:
I want to write a c# program that silently connects local users of a remote machine (win server 2008).

technical problem
I have found a code_project  article that does exactly what I need :http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/RemoteDesktop_CSharpNET.aspx
However after dowloading it I saw this project referenced to AxMSTSCLib.dll (which one of his memebres is  AXHost)

You have to manually create this dll. It wrapps a COM object to be used in vsual studio as a .net object.

I have used the command axImp.exe to create a AxMSTSCLib.dll:
%%\aximp.exe %windir%\system32\mstscax.dll

But there is no Axhost (checked the object browser through visual studio).
so I guess I'm creating this dll the wrong way, but I could find any other way.

here is my dll compared with the one which was donloaded from code-porject
http://drop.io/hidden/eopb4tphk8qekl/asset/Z2V0b2N4LTItanBn
http://drop.io/hidden/eopb4tphk8qekl/asset/bm8tZ2V0LW9jeDItanBn

Anyone knows why? and how can I fix that? or where should i ask this ver specific question?

Regards,

==========

Found the answer. I should have referenced an RDP monitor to the ToolBox and than the dll magically appears right.

I didn't used the ToolBox because I need no GUI. but I guess it's the only way to do this right.

I have got two more questions which I couldn't find answer to
1. Does the dll generated by drugging the RDP monitor is machine-specific?

I mean does this dll differ if created on X86 machine differs from one generated on X64 machine?

2. same question regarding the output of axImp.exe

Thanks

Comment: Found the answer. I should have referenced an RDP monitor to the ToolBox and than the dll magically appears right.

I didn't used the ToolBox because I need no GUI. but I guess it's the only way to do this right.


I have got two more questions which I couldn't find answer to
1. Does the dll generated by drugging the RDP monitor is machine-specific?

I mean does this dll differ if created on X86 machine differs from one generated on X64 machine?

2. same question regarding the output of axImp.exe


Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. I should have referenced an RDP monitor to the ToolBox and than the dll magically appears right. I didn't used the ToolBox because I need no GUI. but I guess it's the only way to do this right. I have got two more questions which I couldn't find answer to 1. Does the dll generated by drugging the RDP monitor is machine-specific? I mean does this dll differ if created on X86 machine differs from one generated on X64 machine? 2. same question regarding the output of axImp.exe Thanks